# Exclude _id field in mongodb while inserting

Tags: mongodb

Is there any possibilities of without having _id field in mongodb collection??
I don't want it because i need to load mongodb data into apache pig, which will not support _id.
So, i just don't want _id field in my mongodb collections.

Anyone please help..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `_id`  - it's required for mongodb, and mongo automatically add this field.

Comment: [**This**](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Pig-Usage#from-a-mongodb-collection) might be of use to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. The `_id` field is required for internal purposes in MongoDB. It is the MongoDB equivalent to a primary key in a relational database. Every document *must* have an unique `_id` field. It does not necessarily need to be an ObjectId, but it must be a value unique to the collection. But you can query data without the ID field:

```
db.yourCollection.find({ ...query... }, { _id: false } );
```

Comment: As I wrote, you can't create a MongoDB document without an _id field. But your actual problem seems to be to import the MongoDB data into Apache Pig without the _id field. That is what you should be asking about.